# Display: Flex not working as expected in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

I am trying to get an sticky footer for my project. During my search I found [**this website**](https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/#article-header-id-3), and I wanted to use the flexbox option.

Now does it work perfect on Chrome and Firefox, but on IE 11 it seems to have trouble with the `display: flex`.

I've tried using `display: -ms-flexbox` but it doesn't help.

Any ideas?

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 0px!important;
}

.container.wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 0px!important;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <header></header>
  <div class="container wrapper"></div>
  <footer>abcd</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Bear in mind that flexbox support on IE is quite flaky:
https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox - See the "Known Issues" for details.

Comment: Because that .container .wrapper gets min-height: 400px in a different stylesheet which I cant edit atm so I used the min-height: 0px to reset that.

Comment: `min-height` is ignored by flex containers in IE. The quick solution is to make the flex container also a flex item (i.e., give the parent `display: flex`) ... https://jsfiddle.net/yLnfrebn/1/